# Does Ext.Onready fire only once per application

Tags: extjs

Let us say I have 5 jsps in my web app and I import the ext-all.js in all 5 jsps. In all 5 jsps, I write an `Ext.onReady(function(){});`

When I hit the first jsp by typing it in the browser url, will all 5 onReady() functions be called? Or only the onReady in jsp 1?

I ask becuase I have the vague idea that onReady event is fired only once per Ext application. So it is different from onLoad() which fires just for the particular page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all five functions passed to `onReady()` will be executed, but each only once. `Ext.onReady` acts as a latch which guarantees the input functions won't execute before the DOM is ready. If `Ext.onReady()` is called *after* "DOM Ready" event, the function will be executed immediately.

Just to make it clear: the "DOM Ready" event only fires once per page load.

---

I've assumed that by "JSP page" you mean "a page fragment", that is all five JSP pages are used to construct a single document and all the JS code is on the same page.
You have to remember that a JSP leaves the server as plain HTML and there is just one HTML document per page (let's forget about iframes, etc., for simplicity).